# How to unlock a Database.mdf file so can share with friends?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Does anyone know how to unlock a SQL Server `.mdf` file so can share with friends?

Because the file that my friend share with me for our group assignment happen to be locked up and that I can't use the data within and only can view it.

Actually I want to share my database with my partner in this group assignment. We use a similar database. However, due to reason of time meet up with our instructor, we both need to have our own holding of a database for presentation at different time.

Also the reason, I want to learn to unlock it is because, we may need to try in on different hardware as well. Is in by Exporting? Like what is shown in this link video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2XmaCFk-kk

Comment: You have tagged MySQL but .MDF is SQL Server? - If its the latter stop the server, copy, restart or send your friend a .BAK backup he can restore.

Comment: Removed the `mysql` tag - `.mdf` files are **Microsoft SQL Server** (not MySQL)

Comment: You basically create your database **on the server**, and anyone connected to that network can use that database - that's the way to "share" your relational database with your friends ...

Comment: What makes you think it's locked up? explain what you are you doing? do you get an error message? If it's urgent then take the time to explain properly

Comment: sorry, actually i want to share my database with my partner in this group assignment. 
and we use the same similar database. 
however, due to reason of time meet up with our instructor, we both need to have our own holding of a database for presentation at different time.

Comment: and again what makes you think its locked up? what are you actually doing?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, to be able to use .mdf/.ldf files in common operations like Copy/Paste you need:

**1. Under Sql Server Management Studio right click on the DB:**

[image]

**2. Then under Detach window check 'Delete Connexions' and click Ok:**
[image]

You're free to do whatever you want with your .mdf/.ldf files

Comment: yes, I was able to do back up for myself with this technique. I had been using it in a while.

thought i was thinking of sharing the DB with my partner by giving him a copy of the DB

Answer (score 1):

Share SQL connection, not the MDF file. Use SQL Surface to enable network access to your DB and define user logins.

Comment: ok, i'll look into this suggestion.
thought this need connected at the same time right?

actually my partner and i will be presenting to our instructor at a different time, so we each need to hold a copy of the database. that is why.

thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: If you need only to copy the database to another PC, you can do one of these: 1) disable SQL service - this will unlock the mdf file; 2) detach the database; 3) make backup and restore it on the other PC.

Comment: sorry, but may i know how to disable SQL service?
i have checked here
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

but didn't really understand.
I am using External SQL server 2012

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't be sharing the MDF files, but if that's what you want to do you will indeed have to detach the database and transfer MDF and LDF files before attaching it on the other side.

It's not completely clear what you want to accomplish, but I think your best option is to take a backup on your machine, transfer the backup to the other machine and restore it there, that way the database doesn't have to go offline.

See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190436.aspx) for a how-to on the backup/restore method.
See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187858.aspx) for instructions on the detach/attach method